# Derivatives of cross products

Tags: calculus, vectors

Why is the derivative of the magnitude of a cross product not equivalent to the magnitude of the derivative of a cross product?  It seems like both would have the same physical representation.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the magnitude of any vector valued function need not be the magnitude of the derivative. The magnitude of the derivative of $(x, y) $ with respect to $x$ is $1$. The derivative of the magnitude is $\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

Comment: True.  I know that they return different results.  My confusion is about WHY they return different results.  The physical representation of the cross product is a vector with a certain length and direction.  The derivative of this is how that vector is changing.  Why does it matter (I know it does matter) if I find the magnitude after finding the derivative compared to finding the magnitude and then take the derivative.  What are these two operations physically representing that are different from each other.

Comment: @Juliet I don't think in terms of physics when I do math, so to me this is simply an algebraic fact. You might want to try Physics SE.

Comment: @Juliet So I asked a physicist, and here's what he said :

Comment: Let $A=v$ be the velocity vector of an object in uniform circular motion. Then $v$ has a constant magnitude (that is, the speed is constant) but a changing direction. Thus $d|v|/dt$=rate of change of speed = 0, but $|dv/dt|=$magnitude of acceleration vector=centripetal acc$=v^2/r$.